# how to set 10 mins before the particular time in Cesium

Tags: javascript, cesiumjs

I was asked to post the particular time on the clock view model. The particular time refers to 1504108564(Wednesday, August 30, 2017 11:56:04 PM GMT+08:00).. I want to set 10 mins before this timing. i want to put pTime in the clock view model.But it does not work... My code is found below...

```
var pTime = 1504108564;
var tenMinuteOffset = Cesium.JulianDate.addSeconds(pTime, -600, new Cesium.JulianDate());

var clock = new Cesium.Clock({
    startTime : tenMinuteOffset,
    currentTime : tenMinuteOffset,
    clockRange : Cesium.ClockRange.LOOP_STOP,
    clockStep : Cesium.ClockStep.SYSTEM_CLOCK_MULTIPLIER
});

var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer', {
    infoBox : false,
    selectionIndicator : false,
    shadows : true,
    clockViewModel: new Cesium.ClockViewModel(clock)
});
```

My question is i want to use this timestamp in the clock... and i want to set 10 mins before the timestamp
Do i need to convert the pTime to readable time? How to do it?

Comment: @emackey oh that is how it work...Thank a lot. but however, if i have a timestamp rather than the readable time, then how should i do it????????

Comment: I updated my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument to `addSeconds` should be a reference to a `Cesium.JulianDate`, not an integer number.

Give this a try:

```
var pTime = Cesium.JulianDate.fromIso8601('2017-08-30T11:56:04+08');
var tenMinuteOffset = Cesium.JulianDate.addSeconds(pTime, -600, new Cesium.JulianDate());

var clock = new Cesium.Clock({
    startTime : tenMinuteOffset,
    currentTime : tenMinuteOffset,
    clockRange : Cesium.ClockRange.LOOP_STOP,
    clockStep : Cesium.ClockStep.SYSTEM_CLOCK_MULTIPLIER
});

var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer', {
    infoBox : false,
    selectionIndicator : false,
    shadows : true,
    clockViewModel: new Cesium.ClockViewModel(clock)
});
```

*EDIT:*  If you really want to start from the timestamp, you can do that, but beware the timestamp doesn't have a timezone baked into it.  So, using the timestamp will have different results based on the timezone setting of the *client's web browser*, not the server.  The first few lines of the above code would look like this:

```
var pTime = 1504108564;
var julian = Cesium.JulianDate.fromDate(new Date(pTime * 1000));
var tenMinuteOffset = Cesium.JulianDate.addSeconds(julian, -600, new Cesium.JulianDate());
```

Comment: 'timezone baked into it' what does this quote means??? Please elaborate more about that...

Comment: A timestamp gives you year, month, day, hour, minute, second, but no timezone.  It is assumed that all timestamps are from the user's current timezone.  So I'm on EDT which is GMT-4, this timestamp gives me `2017-08-30T11:56:04-04` which is 12 hours different from your machine's `2017-08-30T11:56:04+08`.

Comment: `new Date(1504108564 * 1000)` => `Wed Aug 30 2017 11:56:04 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)` on my machine.  Other users will interpret the same timestamp in their own locales.

Comment: so the time will be affected based on the timezone.. So instead of putting timestamp, use the human time..

Comment: @AbdullahShaik Welcome to Stack Overflow, by the way.  This is a community-driven site that runs by allowing members to vote and accept questions and answers.  I noticed you've asked a number of questions, but you haven't voted (up or down arrow) or accepted (green checkmark) any of the answers you've received from myself or others answering your questions.  Can you take a minute to look back at answers you've found helpful and mark them as such?  Thanks!

Comment: Ooops I forgoet about that. thank for remininding me